# How do I add a underscore to a duplicate value in a list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have the following list:

```
poly = ['rs1', 'rs1', 'rs2', 'rs2', 'rs3', 'rs3', 'rs4', 'rs4', 'rs5', 'rs5']
```

All I need is **to add a underscore to duplicate values**, in order to get something like this:

```
['rs1', 'rs1_', 'rs2', 'rs2_', 'rs3', 'rs3_', 'rs4', 'rs4_', 'rs5', 'rs5_']
```

I've checked some similiar public questions but only menage to add a number after each value (therefore getting something like:

```
['rs11', 'rs12', 'rs21', 'rs22', 'rs31', 'rs32', 'rs41', 'rs42', 'rs51', 'rs52']
```

which is definitely far from my aim).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

A more ideomatic version of [PangolinPaws answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743551/7505395)  would be:

```
poly = ['rs1', 'rs1', 'rs2', 'rs2', 'rs3', 'rs3', 'rs4', 'rs4', 'rs5', 'rs5']

seen = set()

for idx, v in enumerate(poly):
    if v in seen:
        poly[idx] = f'{v}_'

    seen.add(v) # sets are unique by nature - no need to put it in an else

print(poly)
```

with the same overall outcome but more performant:

- usage of `set()` makes the "in" checks O(1)
- usage of `enumerate(...)` removes the need of indexing into the list multiple times

Comment: You could even go one step further and omit the indexing altogether by appending the values to a new list instead of modifying the original one.

Comment: @fs I think that would be counterproductive as the OP does not need the original list anymore.  Duplicationg a list of also takes time, memory etc.  Indexing itself is unproblematic - but using enumerate and "locally caching" the value as `v` repalces three `poly[x]` accesses by only some single `poly[x] = ...` if we need to modify.

Comment: I like the approach, but perhaps more descriptive variable names (e.g. `value` and `item_index` instead of `v` and `idx` respectively) would be more helpful for OP if they're relatively new to programming

Answer (score 1):

By looping through your `poly` list and keeping track of elements you've seen before, you can identify and add an `_` to each duplicate in the original list:

```
poly = ['rs1', 'rs1', 'rs2', 'rs2', 'rs3', 'rs3', 'rs4', 'rs4', 'rs5', 'rs5']

already_encountered = []

for x in range(len(poly)):
    if poly[x] in already_encountered:
        poly[x] = f'{poly[x]}_'
    else:
        already_encountered.append(poly[x])

print(poly)
```

Output:

```
['rs1', 'rs1_', 'rs2', 'rs2_', 'rs3', 'rs3_', 'rs4', 'rs4_', 'rs5', 'rs5_']
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner for your decoding pleasure :)

```
[ poly[i] + '_' if poly[i] in poly[:i] else poly[i] for i in range(len(poly)) ]
```

Comment: Please note that this is by no means the most performant solution due to repeated checking of `poly[:i]` but I couldn't resist the code golfing.